# Focus on first form element inside span when span is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't figure out how to focus on the first form element inside a span when the span is clicked. I've included my code, I had also messed around with 'closest' but had no luck.

```
<form>
<span>
  <input id="content" type="text">
  <label for="content">Content</label>
</span>
</form>

$('span').click(function() {
    $(this).find('input').focus()
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before answering your actual question: there is a way to achieve what you're trying to do which doesn't even require any JavaScript.

If you wrap your input field in the label tag, clicking the label will automatically give focus to the field.

```
<form>
    <label>
        Content
        <input id="content" name="content" type="text">
    </label>
</form>
```

---

If you insist on doing it through JavaScript/jQuery, you'll have to make sure you only attach the click handler after the DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () { // Or equivalent: $(function() { ... });
    $('span').click(function () {
        $(this).find('input:first').focus(); // :first makes sure only the first input found is selected
    });
});
```

Comment: I see Lucky Soni beat me to pretty much exactly the same. I'll keep my answer though, as it shows a different approach: using `<label>` as a wrapper of the `<input>`, rather than using the `for` attribute.

Comment: Initially I was using the label tag to wrap the input, but ran into an issue when I had a select and an input inside the same label. When I would click the input, the select would then steal focus. I'll continue to use the label as a wrapper of the input where I can though.

Answer (score 3):

why not use the label to trigger this functionality
the `span` will only cover the `label` and `input` so if i understand correctly you want the focus to be set on the `input` even when the user clicks the `lable` which can be achieved like so:

```
<form>
    <span>
       <input name="content" id="content" type="text">
       <label for="content">Content</label>
    </span>
</form>
```

But if you are trying to do something else then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('span').click(function() {
     $(this).find('input:first').focus();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your js is called after the DOM is loaded

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('span').click(function() {
      $(this).find('input').focus()
    });
  });
</script>
```